# How to find differences in Python between two sizable 2D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

[Difference array with junk values(All those large numbers are wrong while smaller ones are correct )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2MSG.jpg) Taking a difference between two significant 2Darrays presents a challenge for me. Although it adds junk values in between, the majority of the different components have the correct difference value.
But when I try to log the array to CSV, it adds some trash numbers like 6500 and 8000 in some cells that should only contain much lower values like 8,10. I need to calculate the mean of z, and it's giving me a very huge figure. Only a small subset of cells have this issue, and the majority of them have the correct difference. If someone could assist me with this, I would be very appreciative.

Here is the code that I am trying to execute.
Note that yuv_frames and yuv_frames_temp give a list with the shape [2160, 3840].

```
import numpy as np
import yuvio
import csv
yuv_frames = yuvio.mimread("test.yuv", 3840, 2160, 'yuv420p16le', 1,1)
yuv_frame_temp =yuvio.mimread ("test.yuv," 3840, 2160, 'yuv420p16le', 1+30,1)

x = np.array(yuv_frames[0]. y)
y = np.array(yuv_frame_temp[0].y)
s = (2160, 3840)
z = np.zeros(s)
z = np.subtract(x,y)
```

Comment: How did you get these numbers? They look like negative numbers, but are formatted as unsigned integers. It may be better to solve the problem from the source.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `numpy.mean`, you can specify `where`, which is an array of Booleans to use.
You can generate such an array by comparing your original array with a value:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.random.randint(256, size=10)
Out[2]: array([127, 123, 133,  37,  89,  32,  44,  12,  69,  76])

In [3]: select = x < 120
Out[3]: 
array([False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True])

In [4]: np.mean(x, where=select)
Out[4]: 51.285714285714285

In [5]: np.mean(x)
Out[5]: 74.2
```